# How to resolve SimpleMembership adding advanced time for createddate(datetime)?

Tags: datetime, model-view-controller, simplemembership

I have implemented Simple Membership for my app's login and User Profile. The application is always creating membership records with createdon datetime stamp as 6 hours advanced.

Please let me know how I can override the time settings of the membership records created in database since we are handling a specific time limit for the user's account activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had actually identified that Simple Membership by default uses the UTC time and hence shown the difference from my posted time.
Hence we have added an adjustment with our time zone while using the time from Membership tables.
I apologize for the late response.